How to use react-email in react not next.js?
How do you send email component from froment to backend using react and express?
I created a email component using react email api and now stuck as how to share it with server?
component
import * as React from 'react';
import { Html, Button } from "@react-email/components";

export function Email(props) {
  const { url } = props;

  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Button href={url}>Click me</Button>
    </Html>
  );
}

export default Email;

express resend ex:
import { Resend } from 'resend';
import { Email } from './email';

const resend = new Resend('re_123456789');

await resend.emails.send({
  from: 'you@example.com',
  to: 'user@gmail.com',
  subject: 'hello world',
  react: **Here in next js you can call Email()**,
});

I searched all over web only examples I found were of next.js is it not possible to use plain react?

What do you mean by "send [an] email component" in this case?  How does one "share a component with [the] server"?  Are you just asking how to send email from client-side JavaScript code?  From server-side JavaScript code?  Something else?  Please edit the question to clarify the problem you are trying to solve.

@David I edit question as per your request.

The vendor's documentation has four examples.  Two of them use Next, two of them do not.  It looks like you're trying to use a Next example, but claiming to want to use a different one.  Maybe you just clicked on the wrong example?  If you want to use Express and not Next then you probably want to start from the vendor's Express example.

@David Thx for link but after I tried using it in react it shows cors error how do I solve that?

Step 1: Examine the actual and exact error.  Step 2: Use your favorite search engine to research that error.  Step 3: Apply what you learn to your application.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.
